# How to add a new List page(listforms) in survey list using c# dynamically?

Tags: list, development, list-form, survey

I have created the custom page named 'preview.aspx' in survey list by using SharePoint designer.and I have added some functionality to it.

I need to add this file to Sharepoint list form pages using c# (through web part code behind).also, 
In this process, I changed the list name and list id dynamically.It's not working.

it's working when we deploying without changing the list name. I am not sure about this 
I have tried the below code...

```
Currentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPList list = Currentweb.Lists.TryGetList(surveyName);
string _listID = list.ID.ToString();
var path = SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SurveyRefactoring\preview.aspx", 15);
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
FileCreationInformation();
string ListId = "ListId=\"" + _listID + "\"";

SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
Guid defaultView = list.DefaultView.ID;
Guid otherView = list.Views["All Tasks"].ID;


text = text.Replace("ListId=\"c2e41257-aadf-4605-8e64-ecc51c7c8d90\"", ListId);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);
FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

SPFile newForms = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(list.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + list.RootFolder.Url + "/preview.txt", file);
```

It throwing an invalid file error message in the last line(Adding page in the list) Any help?